# Xcode 5 -No matching provisioning profiles found

Tags: xcode5, provisioning-profile

Having a problem here with Xcode 5. I was developing an app and suddenly my Xcode crashed. Now I am not able to enter that same app again. Under the Team (none) its keep on writing me: No matching provisioning profiles found - this project must be build by using provisioning profile.

But I haven't changed anything.. If i open my app in simulator it runs normal. I don't understand. Provisioning profile cost 99$ but I'm learning for now.

Please help!

Comment: You cannot test on hardware without a provisioning file (requires Apple developer account). If you were running on hardware before then you must need to re-download your provisioning file.

Comment: I haven't tried to put my app on my phone or iPad. I was just programming like always. And after crash i can't enter my project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I solved out my problem by importing my old project from project foder to my new project. Still don't know what went wrong in other project.